# setting label month in Y-axis chart reporting services

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting, business-intelligence

My problem is concerning a chart in reporting services.

My dataset is looking as below:

```
MonthDue        MonthDeleviry
Jan-2011        Mars-2011
Feb-2012        Jun_2013
Aug-2016        Oct-014
```

I want to make a graphique MonthDue(Y-axis) /.MonthDeleviry(X-axis) the problem is that Y-axis doesen't show label of month and convert it to FirstDayMonth/MM/YYYY. It seems that this axis dont accepte String value and allow just Numeric and date Format (dd/mm/YYYY)

Excuse my bad english

Can you help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the Y axis accepts a datetime but your data is a string of the format given, you could convert that string into a datetime for the start of that month.

```
=cdate("1-" & Fields!MonthDue)
```

Use this expression in the "Value" field of the "Values" tab when you edit the data in the chart properties.

Hope that helps.